# SharePoint 2013 Promoted Links in Elements.xml?

Tags: 2013, elements-xml, promoted-links

Does anyone have a working example of an <AllUserWebPart> or <View> within an Elements.xml file that includes a "Promoted Links" web part on a page. I just can't seem to get my XsltListViewWebPart to work for some reason. I can't predict the GUID of the list / view because the Promoted Links is being created by the same deployment package so I need to use ListUrl or equivalent. At the moment I think I'm going to have to fall back on code in the feature activation event receiver which would be a shame. Appreciate any help.

Comment: And for an additional bonus point, anyone know why it keeps stripping "Hi. " from the start of my question?

Comment: It is a built in functionality (the stripping) to keep the posts clean